# AAD authentication supported for Azure SQL DW currently?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

It looks like Azure Active Directory authentication is in preview for Azure SQL Database. Is it also in preview for Azure SQL Data Warehouse or is it currently supported?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Active Directory integration is available for [SQL Data Warehouse](http://aka.ms/sqldw). You can read how to enable Active Directory integration on the [Authentication to Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-authentication) page.

Comment: Thanks Matt. The quick response is much appreciated. You are so fast I have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer :)